# Changing a Inputfields with Tab in Mobile version of keyboard. (C#, NGUI)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ngui

Is posible make a option to change a input field with this button in mobile keyboard?
[Keyboard in my smartphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nYIh.jpg) 
I dont know how to make something like that in my application. I add to update this

```
 void Update()
    {
        if (emailInput.isSelected)
        {
            if (nextInput != null && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
            {
                UICamera.selectedObject = nextInput;
            }
        }
    }
```

With Public Game Object to each Input.

Comment: If you use InputField component then the keyboard is opening by default when you tap the text area

Comment: @Everts I know but i need change type of this default Keyboard that have a option to change inputs

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need but have you tried to look into the touch keyboard class? There are some parameters to pass so you can control it. It is limited compared to native touch keyboard but it could be a start. Maybe define what is the type you are after.